# Finding the String Length in Assembly x86 IRVINE32

Tags: assembly, x86, irvine32

I'm new to assembly programming and I'm trying to figure out the last piece of the puzzle to this program. When I display a string ("Hello") it shows up as 0 instead of 5. Why is this happening and what do I need to do to change this?

```
TITLE 


INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data

prompt       BYTE   "Enter String: ", 0
response     BYTE   50 DUP(0)
message      BYTE   " Message entered. ",0

.code   

STRQRY       PROC
             push   ebp
             mov    ebp, esp
             push   edx
             push   ecx

             mov    edx, [ebp+8]
             call   writestring

             mov    ecx, SIZEOF response
             mov    edx, OFFSET response
             call   readstring



             pop    ecx
             pop    edx
             pop    ebp  
             ret    4

STRQRY       ENDP

STRLEN       PROC 
             push   ebp 
             mov    ebp, esp
             push   ebx
             push   ecx

             mov    edx,[ebp+8]
             call   writedec

             mov    eax, 0


counter:
             mov    cl,[edx+eax]

             cmp    cl, 0      

             JE     done

             inc    eax 

             jmp    counter

done:
             pop    ecx
             pop    ebx
             pop    ebp
             ret    4

STRLEN       ENDP

main         PROC

             push   OFFSET prompt
             call   STRQRY



             push   eax 
             call   STRLEN

             mov    edx,OFFSET message
             call   WriteString

             mov    edx, OFFSET response
             call   WriteString

             exit
main         ENDP
END          main
```

Comment: why ebp+16 in strlen? It looks to me the same situation as strqry, which is doing only ebp+8 ... check it in debugger, if you load the correct argument.

Comment: I edited the code, I almost figured it out. It seems the crash happens at the counter when I `cmp cl, 0`

Comment: `cmp cl,0` can't crash in any way. It's probably the memory access ahead of it, having invalid `edx+eax` address. So let it crash in debugger, and check the register values, which are unexpected, then try to figure out how it happened. Or restart and debug it by small steps here and there, putting breakpoints into parts which you didn't verify yet.

Answer (score 0):

You say you want to find out the length of the input string, but that is exactly what the IRVINE32 *readstring* function returns in the EAX register!

---

> ```
> mov    ecx, SIZEOF response
> mov    edx, OFFSET response
> call   readstring
> ```

In this block ECX is supposed to be 1 less than the size of the input buffer that you're providing. This allows for adding a NULL terminator.  You defined *response* as 50 bytes, so `mov ecx, 49` would be OK.

---

> ```
> call   STRQRY
> ***HERE EAX HAS THE LENGTH OF THE INPUT!***
> push   eax 
> call   STRLEN
> ```

When the *STRLEN* procedure runs it expects **an address** as an argument, but you provide it with **a length**! That's the stuff that crashes are made of.

```
 mov    edx, [bp+8]   <<< This needs to be the ADDRESS to start at!
 mov    eax, 0
counter:
 mov    cl,[edx+eax]
 ...
```

---

> ```
>   mov    edx,[ebp+8]
>   call   writedec
>   mov    eax, 0
>  counter:
>   mov    cl,[edx+eax]
>   cmp    cl, 0      
>   JE     done
>   inc    eax 
>   jmp    counter
>  done:
> ```

In this code your using *writedec* at the wrong place! EAX doesn't have the length from your calculation at this point. Move the `call writedec` below the *done* label.

---

In your *STRLEN* procedure you `push`/`pop` the EBX register where you should be saving/restoring the EDX register.

---

In summary, this is how the *STRLEN* procedure could look like:

```
STRLEN       PROC 
    push   ebp 
    mov    ebp, esp
    push   edx
    push   ecx
    mov    edx, [bp+8]
    mov    eax, 0
counter:
    mov    cl, [edx+eax]
    cmp    cl, 0
    JE     done
    inc    eax
    jmp    counter
done:
    call   writedec         <<< Length calculated by you
    pop    ecx
    pop    edx
    pop    ebp
    ret    4
STRLEN       ENDP
```

and how to call it:

```
    push   OFFSET prompt
    call   STRQRY
    call   writedec         <<< Length given by ReadString
    push   OFFSET response
    call   STRLEN
```